# Removing the extra content when using knitr in markdown

Tags: r, web-scraping, knitr

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis', comment=NA, warning=FALSE, message = FALSE} 
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("TYU2.F", src = "yahoo", verbose = TRUE, from = "2018-05-01")
tyu2 <- data.frame(TYU2.F)
tyu <- c(tyu2$TYU2.F.Open)
ggplot(data = tyu2 , aes(x=1:29,y=tyu))+geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue")+
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,30,1))+
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,0.2,0.01))
```
````

This code works properly and gives the output. But when i copy into markdown and knit. The plot is shown with the all the process(Down). How to remove this.

```
downloading TYU2.F 
done. [1] “TYU2.F”
```

Also is there a way i can insert in here some shiny code chuncks so that it becomes a bit more interactive while knitting

Comment: This has to do with the type of the code chunk. Please include this info in your question, and also refer to this:https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_rcodechunks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new RMarkdown file, the first chunk is set as `{r setup, include=FALSE}`

You should switch to `include=TRUE`

Comment: what if i also want to remove the comments

Comment: You should have a look here : [link](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_rcodechunks.html)